# table_exists() method might not be working properly

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm starting to write a simple Model class using codeigniter 2.1.0. All that I want it to do for now is create and delete the MySQL table it represents. Here's the code:

```
<?php

    class Users_model extends CI_Model {

        public function createTable(){

            if( $this->db->table_exists('users') == FALSE ){

                $query = "CREATE TABLE users(
                        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
                        email  VARCHAR(52) NOT NULL check(email <> ''),
                        UNIQUE (email)
                        )ENGINE = InnoDB;";

                $this->db->query($query);

            }

        }

        public function deleteTable(){

            if( $this->db->table_exists('users') ){

                $query = "DROP TABLE users;";

                $this->db->query($query);

            } else {

                echo "users not found <br />";

                $tables = $this->db->list_tables();
                foreach ($tables as $table)
                {
                    echo $table."<br />";
                }
            }

        }


    }

?>
```

And this is the code I'm executing in the main class:

```
$this->load->model('users_model');
$this->users_model->deleteTable();
$this->users_model->createTable();
```

The first run is fine and dandy. The tables are created just fine. But then, when I run it again, I get the output:

```
users not found
users
```

Upon further inspection I realize `table_exists()` never returns `TRUE`. `var_dump($this->db->table_exists('users'));` returns `bool(false)`.

So, am I doing something wrong? This is as simple as it gets, copy pasted from the [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/table_data.html). Google doesn't return anything related, and being a C programmer my mindset is always "If there's a bug, it's yours. (Richard Stallman is never wrong)"... But since Mr. Stallman has little to do with this, there's a possibility.

### TL;DR

Why does `table_exists('users')` in the above code never returns `TRUE` even if `list_tables()` does return 'users';

Comment: what does `var_dump($this->db->table_exists('users'));` say?

Comment: @StefanN Thank you, now we can assert it does indeed return bool(false). What's next :P

Comment: ok well... looks good. did you make sure (directly on the mysql server, maybe using phpMyAdmin) that the users table does exist (in the right database) ? seems odd..

Comment: The table is there, phpMyAdmin and list_tables() both concur in that the table is there and it's called 'users'. I checked for blank spaces before and after, put the name through an ascii to hex. Don't know where the problem might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `var_dump()` instead of `echo`. Boolean values don't work well with `echo`.

```
var_dump( $this->db->table_exists('users') );
```

The [source code](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/DB_driver.php#L829) of `table_exists` looks like this:

```
function table_exists($table_name)
{
    return ( ! in_array($this->_protect_identifiers($table_name, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), $this->list_tables())) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}
```

**Update** from comments

If you have a look at [_protect_identifiers](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/DB_driver.php#L1351) it does add the database name to the table name. But there should be a . between `db.table`. Maybe your db config is messed up?

Comment: Try to edit `system/database/DB_driver.php` and var_dump the result of `_protect_identifiers`. Maybe the is something odd. or is there a space after the table name or something?

Comment: Ok, just did. And I think we are into something. The dump from $this->_protect_identifiers is string(12) "aidcusers" array(3) { [0]=> string(8) "usuarios" }. "aidcusers" is kind of a mistery, aidc is the server name, but I have no idea where that string came from. BUT the array has an array in it, and if the function in_array is not recursive this might be the reason why it returns false.

Comment: If you have a look at [_protect_identifiers](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/DB_driver.php#L1351) it does add the database name. But there should be a `.` between db.table. Maybe your db config is messed up?

Answer (score 2):

As a solution to your problem in codeigniter you can try this function

```
function validateTable($tableName)
    {
        $result = $this->db->list_tables();

        foreach( $result as $row ) {
            if( $row == $tableName )    return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll end up doing that since we discovered the problem might be in the DB configuration; and that's dangerous territory at this stage. Although it didn't answered the question, it's a neat workaround so +1.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to this, you could use a method to list all tables(in link), store them in an array

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
echo "Table: {$row[0]}\n";
//search array here
}
```

You could follow example 1 on the following link:

http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-tables.php

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar problem with this function.

I am using a script to create the tables that my site require, if the function table_exists() determines that any of the required tables are missing.  I keep seeing a strange problem where, on the first page load, several database insertions did not seem to be happening.  I thought there was a problem with my insert statements, but I could not find a single error.  Also, everything seemed to work just fine after the first page load.  It turns out that the table creation script was actually being called several times, re-creating an empty table each time.

I'm assuming that the results returned by multiple calls to table_exists() do not change based on tables that are created after it is called (the first time).

I also tried to use the solution given by Shayan Husaini.  list_tables(); also seems to respond the same way.  It will not return new tables that have been created after it has been called.

I eventually fixed this problem by tracking every table that was created during a page load.  Still, I feel that these functions should be able to find new tables that have been added to the database after these functions have been called one (or more) times.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue with CodeIgniter 3 when trying to use table_exists() in a migrations context. (It seems to work as expected in other points in my code.)

For MySQL, here is a cheap-and-cheerful replacement:

```
if(is_null($this->db->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '{$tableName}'")->row()))
{
    //echo "Table {$tableName} does not exist";
}
```

Although, annoyingly, this replacement doesn't seem happy with CI's database caching switched on.

:-/

OK, so I've just been fishing around in the code and, while it doesn't look like a bug, it's definitely good-to-know:

**DB_driver.php**

- ::table_exists() which depends on:
- ::list_tables() which can pull the table name list out of its own **"per instantiation" cache** or by the query provided by:
- ::_list_tables() [in the mysqliOrWhatever_driver.php in question] which, for MySQL, is a 'SHOW TABLES FROM theSchemaName' query

**DB_forge.php**

Following methods can potentially affect the "per instantiation"
cache of DB_driver.php:

- ::create_table() [UPDATE no! it doesn't update the cached list of tables. This is the quirk for me!]
- ::drop_table()
- ::rename_table()

(Makes sense right?)

Comment: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/commit/593ce680b87fadb05af6ba13c857ef8b16303bcf fixes a small issue around this topic

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me

```
$YOUR_TABLE_NAME="XYZ";
if ($this->db->table_exists($YOUR_TABLE_NAME) )
{
  echo "table exists";
}
else
{
  echo "table does not exist";
}
```