# MySQL check if table already exists

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have couple of tables in my MySQL database. They have a certain naming convention such as.

```
tbl_1_alpha
tbl_1_beta
tbl_1_alpha2
tbl_2_beta
tbl_3_alpha2
```

Now I want to check wether a given table is already exists in the database.

eg.

- `$name = 'tbl_1_alpha'`  -> exists
- `$name = 'tbl_1_alpha2'`  -> exists
- `$name = 'tbl_1_alpha3'`  -> does not exists

To get the result I used the following functions

```
 public function exists($name)
    {

        $query = "SHOW TABLES LIKE '$name%'";

        $result = $this->db->query($query);

        if ($result->num_rows() > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
```

for a given `$name` = `tbl_1_alpha` it return `true`. But When I delete the table `tbl_1_alpha` it still returns `true` because it matches the name to `tbl_1_alpha2`. How can I avoid that?

Can anyone help me to match the exact table name and figure out wether it is already exist or not?

Comment: why not check the full name, no wild cards, no LIKE

Comment: possible this might help you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479056/table-exists-method-might-not-be-working-properly

Comment: Seriously, how did I not see the `%`. Thanks @Dagon

Comment: That's a naming convention? I'm glad I'm no part of this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check if a MySQL table exists with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432178/how-can-i-check-if-a-mysql-table-exists-with-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need of query. just run this

```
$this->db->table_exists('customer');
```

[Table Data](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/table_data.html)

---

**Example**

```
$query = $this->db->table_exists('customer');
$count = count($query);

if (empty($count)) {
    echo "No Table Found";
}
elseif ($count == 1) {
    echo "Oopzz! There is table";
}
elseif ($count >1) {
    echo "Ohh !! There are many tables";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$check_exists = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$name'");
$table_exists = mysql_num_rows($check_exists) > 0;
if ($table_exists) {
    echo 'table exists';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just remove the wild card from the query.
i.e.

```
$query = "SHOW TABLES LIKE '$name'";
```

Given, of course, that it's not a requirement.

**Without `LIKE` :**

Fair enough if you don't want to use the LIKE clause, here's the query without it. It either returns `1` or `0` depending on whether the table exists or not.

```
SELECT count((1)) as `ct`  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_schema ='database' and table_name='table';
```

And there are many other ways too which are already answered. Checkout them here : [How can I check if a MySQL table exists with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432178/how-can-i-check-if-a-mysql-table-exists-with-php)

Comment: oh the wildcard. I feel so dumb.

Comment: if your not using wild cards why are you still using LIKE?

Comment: @Dagon how can I write the query without the `LIKE` keyword.

Comment: @Dagon because I thought that was the easiest way. But I've updated the answer to do that without LIKE.