# Finding if table exists or not in MySQL with codeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to check whether MySQL table presents or not in the database. I am using CodeIgniter 3.* v

```
 if($this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `$table` Limit 1")->result() == TRUE){
    #next process if table found    
    }else{
    #display error
    }
```

I am finding solution on [How can I check if a MySQL table exists with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432178/how-can-i-check-if-a-mysql-table-exists-with-php)

Comment: Did you try it? Are you getting errors? Not clear what you are asking.

Comment: A little searching and in the user guide there is a function for that. https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/db_driver_reference.html?highlight=table_exists#CI_DB_driver::table_exists. You should try reading the user guide more!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL check if table already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259886/mysql-check-if-table-already-exists)

Answer (score 14):

Try this

```
if ($this->db->table_exists($table) )
{
  // table exists some code run query
}
else
{
  // table does not exist
}
```

Comment: Why did you stop using your nick Woflgang1983? I'm just wondering as I remember your avatar and nick as we exchanged some Q/A since quite a while...

Comment: @Vickel Having a rest from that nick name for a while until maybe think of some thing better or I might go back to it.